# Inverse image sheaf of an $\mathcal{O}_Y$ Module

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, sheaf-theory

I am trying to understand the inverse image sheaf since I am not comfortable with sheafification and taking direct limits. So I tried to prove the following to help my understanding:

> Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a map of (locally) ringed topological spaces. Let $\mathcal{G}$ be an $\mathcal{O}_Y$ module. Show that $f^{-1}\mathcal{G}$ is an $f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y$ module.

My attempt:

Given any $U \in X$ open, we know that the inverse image presheaf $f^{-1,pre}\mathcal{G}(U)$ is given by lim$_{V \supseteq f(U)}\mathcal{G}(V)$. So any element in the sheafification of this will be given by a function $s:U\rightarrow \bigcup_{p \in U}f^{-1,pre}\mathcal{G}_p$.

Now given that stalks on the inverse image presheaf $f^{-1,pre}\mathcal G_p$ are isomorphic to stalks on $\mathcal G_{f(p)}$, we get that any element of the sheafification is given by a function $s: U \rightarrow \bigcup _{p \in U}\mathcal{G}_{f(p)}$. Similarly, any element in $f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y(U)$ is given by a function $r:U \rightarrow \bigcup_{p \in U} \mathcal{O}_{Y,f(p)}$.

So we can define the module structure as $(r \cdot s)(p) = r(p)\cdot s(p)$ where the multiplication on the right is given by the module structure of $\mathcal{G}_{f(p)}$ as an $\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(p)}$ module induced by the $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module structure on $\mathcal G$.

Since we are using the induced module structure on stalks, this does indeed define a module and we only need to check that the module structure defined respects restrictions. But $(rs)|_{V}(p) = r(p)s(p)|_V = r|_V(p) = s|_V(p)$ for any $V \subseteq U$ open. And we are done.

My questions:

1. Is the module structure and reasoning for why it defines a module structure correct?
2. I'm a bit unsure about how to explicitly write out the restriction maps and so would appreciate any explanation on how the restriction map explicitly works (viewed as restrictions of the functions r,s - if my understanding till there was fine)
3. Is there anything else that needs to be checked aside from the module structure and restriction maps that I am missing.

Thanks

Comment: You still need to verify that the function $p \mapsto r(p) \cdot s(p)$ locally comes from some section of $f^{-1,pre} \mathcal{G}$ - since not every function $U \to \bigcup_{p \in U} \mathcal{G}_{f(p)}$ gives an element of the sheafification, only the ones satisfying that condition.

Comment: Also, you need to provide an argument why the multiplication map you give actually makes $f^{-1} \mathcal{G}$ into an $f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_Y$-module, i.e. why it is that for each open set, $f^{-1} \mathcal{G}(U)$ does form an $f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_Y(U)$-module under the multiplication map on $U$ that you give?

Comment: I see what you mean by the second point but not the first. What do you mean by $p \mapsto r(p) \cdot s(p)$ locally comes from a section of $f^{-1,pre}\mathcal G$? Isn't that a given since $\mathcal G_{f(p)} = f^{-1,pre}\mathcal G_f(p)$ and that $r(p) \cdot s(p) $ is in $\mathcal G_{f(p)}$. Or am i misunderstanding what you're saying?

Comment: Recall that if $\mathcal{F}$ is a presheaf, then its sheafification $\mathcal{F}^+$ can be described by $\mathcal{F}^+(U)$ being the set of functions $f : U \to \bigcup_{p\in U} \mathcal{F}_p$ such that (a) $f(p) \in \mathcal{F}_p$ for each $p \in U$ (b) for each $p \in U$, there exists some open $V$ with $p \in V \subseteq U$ and some $x \in \mathcal{F}(V)$ such that $f(p) = x_p \in \mathcal{F}_p$ for each $p\in V$.  The (a) condition is pretty easy to see from the definition (and was implicit anyway); it's the (b) condition that needs a bit more work to show in this case.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a map of topological spaces and if $A$ is a sheaf of rings on $Y$ you define the presheaf on $X$:

$$F_A(U):=lim_{f(U) \subseteq V}A(V).$$

Since $A(V)$ is a ring for all $V$ and since $F_A(U)$ is a direct limit of rings it follows $F_A(U)$ is a presheaf of rings on $X$. It follows $F_A^+:=f^{-1}(A)$ is a sheaf of rings on $X$. Hence the inverse image of a sheaf of rings is a sheaf of rings. If $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a map of schemes there is a canonical map of sheaves of rings

$$ f^{\#}: f^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_Y) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X.$$

If $E$ is a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_Y$-modules it follows $f^{-1}(E)$ is a sheaf of $f^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_Y)$-modules:

Since $E(V)$ is an $\mathcal{O}_Y(V)$-module for all $V$ it follows
$lim_{f(U) \subseteq V} E(V)$ is a $lim_{f(U)\subseteq V}\mathcal{O}_Y(V)$-module for all $U$,
hence $f^{-1}(E)(U)$  is an $f^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_Y)(U)$-module for all $U$.
It follows that $f^{-1}(E)$ is an $f^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_Y)$-module.
You define the following presheaf

$$ F_{f^*E}(U):= \mathcal{O}_X(U)\otimes_{f^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_Y(U)}f^{-1}(E)(U)$$

and define

$$ f^*E:=F^+_{f^*E}:=\mathcal{O}_X \otimes_{f^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_Y)} f^{-1}(E)$$

which is canonically a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules.

**Question:**   "1. Is the module structure and reasoning for why it defines a module structure correct? 2. I'm a bit unsure about how to explicitly write out the restriction maps and so would appreciate any explanation on how the restriction map explicitly works (viewed as restrictions of the functions r,s - if my understanding till there was fine)
3. Is there anything else that needs to be checked aside from the module structure and restriction maps that I am missing."

**Answer:** Instead of working with stalks it is better to work with direct limits and tensor products. Then the module structure is "canonical".

Comment: "If $E$ is a sheaf of $\mathscr{O}_Y$-modules it follows $f^{-1}(E)$ is a sheaf of $f^{-1}(\mathscr{O}_Y)$-modules": that's precisely what the OP is asking for the details on how to verify that statement.